# Why "they" chose to raise an exception?

Tags: python, exception, standard-library

I was reading about the [hasattr built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the
>   string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if not.
>   (**This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing
>   whether it raises an AttributeError or not.**)

emphasis mine.

I don't get the point of check whether the `getattr` function raises an `AttributeError` or not, since it would be significantly faster search for the attribute itself (in case the exception is raised).

When I use a standard library I expect that it was written in the best possible way. Is to raise an exception really the best possible way to implement `hasattr` in this case?

Comment: Note that in CPython, `hasattr` does not literally call the `getattr` builtin; rather, its C implementation `PyObject_HasAttr` calls `PyObject_GetAttr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot always search for the attribute; if the object implements a dynamic [`__getattr__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) for example, or overrides [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

The only *reliable* method to verify an attribute exists is to use `getattr()`.

Comment: Of course, Python *could* have been designed to require (or allow) a `__hasattr__` hook. However, such a design would violate DRY and introduce discrepancies between getting an attribute and querying for one. If an attribute access is so slow that it justifies a separate query for its existence, then it likely shouldn't be exposed as an attribute in the first place. For potentially heavy-weight computed contents it is a much better idea to use a method.

Answer (score 0):

The class could have overridden `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` to present attributes  that do not exist in `__dict__`.

To be consistent with `getattr()`, `hasattr()` needs to have knowledge of those attributes. One easy yet generic way to achieve this is by calling `getattr()` and seeing whether that succeeds.